# Twitter retweets amount

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I wonder if anyone could help me to figure out how to get the amount, as a Java `long` number, of all retweets of me looking at a specific user, using either twitters API or Twitter4J.
The code below gives me only the last 100 retweets, using Twitter4J!

```
public static long getReTweets(){
   long amount = 0;
   Twitter tweeter = new TwitterFactory().getOAuthAuthorizedInstance(MyUser.getUserAccessToken());
   try {
      ResponseList retweets = tweeter.getRetweetsOfMe();
      amount = retweets.size();
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return amount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be warned: the retweets returned by the Twitter API are only "new-style" retweets. A lot of people make old-style retweets. To get the full picture, you need to add together the two types.

To find & count old style retweets, you can either collect your mentions, then pick out the RTs, or do a search for "RT @you some keywords".

Answer (score 1):

with Twitter4J you can call the `getRetweetsOfMe(Paging)` to resolve additional pages of retweets. The 100 result count is the API [limit](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/retweets_of_me) so you should keep calling the method till you're done.

Answer (score 1):

According to Twitter Developer site, [retweet_of_me](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/retweets_of_me), you can allow a count of maximum 100 results.

> **count**        Specifies the number
>   of records to retrieve. Must be less
>   than or equal to 100.
>
> http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweets_of_me.json?count=5

So, if you want to get **all** `retweet_of_me`, you'll need to page through all your retweets_of_me and do a `count` of a 100. Sum up all resulting counts till you don't get any results from a page and that's the total retweets_of_me.

PS. The more pages you have, the more work it might take for you to page all of it.